# Cannot pass lambda expression as reference

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I have this code sample:

```
#include <iostream>

void
foo( int & value )
{
    value += 5;
}

template< class T >
void
foo( T value )
{
    value();
}

template < class T >
void bar( T & val )
{
    foo( val );
}

int main()
{

int i = 0;
bar( i );
std::cout << i << std::endl;
// prints: 5

bar( [](){ std::cout << "ok1" << std::endl; } );
// prints: ok1

[]()
{
    bar(
        [](){ std::cout << "ok2" << std::endl; } );
}();
// error:
/*
test.cpp(36) : error C2664: 'void bar<void(__cdecl *)(void)>(T &)' : cannot conv
ert argument 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'void (__cdecl *&)(void)'
        with
        [
            T=void (__cdecl *)(void)
        ]

*/

}
```

Can someone explain why first time ("ok1") lambda converts successful, but in case of nesting ("ok2") it "cannot convert" ?

P.S. ofc it works well when I use "universal reference" argument in that template function, but I'm interesting of understanding.

Comment: I would expect the first one not to work either since the template function bar it requires a non-const reference

Comment: But first one compiles with vc12. I'm a little confused.

Comment: Smells like non-standard lvalue-reference-to-rvalue binding...

Comment: should be signaled as a compiler bug? I don't know what does the standard allows in this case

Comment: Both calls to `bar` with the lambda argument are illegal because you're trying bind an rvalue to a non-`const` lvalue reference. VS2013 will warn you of that in the first case if you compile with `/W4`. No idea why it chokes on the second one.

Answer (score 1):

This works. Does it help you?

```
auto l = [](){ std::cout << "ok2" << std::endl; };
[&l]()
{
   bar(l);
}();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It works because "l" is lvalue already and does not require conversion.